# Cocoa control for keywords/tags

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, tags, keyword

I want to build a keyword/tag feature for my Cocoa application. Is there a tutorial or example of how a control that sets keywords/tags works? I want it to look something like the Keywords window in iPhoto that you get from Window->Show Keywords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a built in control for this called [NSTokenField](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTokenField_Class/index.html), it's a simple subclass of a NSTextField. You supply a string and a set of delimiters and it automatically tokenizes them.